# Android Calculator Error

Tags: android, calculator

I have two questions:

1. How do I adjust the buttons in a table, like a normal calculator?
2. Whenever I click the 'equal' button the app is closing -Force
   Close.

I think the problem comes from the int sum=0; whenever I use it at the equal place it gives the error.

[code](http://pastebin.com/rarEg0yk)

Comment: always look at LogCat to see the stack trace. In most cases it exactly tells why and where it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

For adjusting buttons, use `TableLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, where you can position buttons relatively to others.
Concerning second question, just change

```
display.setText(sum);
```

to

```
display.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

To make your calculator work at least a little bit change `equal.setOnClickListener` to this:

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            display.setText(String.valueOf(counter+sum));
                            counter=0;
                            sum=0;
                    }
            });
```

Comment: Ok so display.setText(String.valueOf(sum)); does work and TableLayout aswell. Just need to fix something because when I do 1+1 it gives me 1.

Comment: Of course it does, when you press 1, value of counter is 0*10+1=1, then you press + and value of counter changes to 0 and sum becomes 1, the you press 1 again, counter becomes 0*10+1=1 and finaliy you press equals and display value of sume, thus 1;

Answer (score 0):

use this code it may help

```
display.setText(sum+"");
```

because you have declared sum as int and setText property accepts CharSequence